# React Need help getting my component update after State Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is my first own React project and I'm basically trying to make a recipe add.

My structure looks as follows:

- App.js
- AllRecipes.js
- Recipe.js
- Comments.js
- AddComment.js

My biggest problem right now is that when I add a new Comment.

`this.state` in *App.js* updates.
But it doesn't send the updated data down to my component and that's what I can't figure out.

Right now I send my data through the NavLink as states.

```
<NavLink to={{pathname: '/recipe/' + recipe.Name, state: { recipe: recipe, key: recipe.id }}}>{recipe.Name}</Link>
```

Then from Recipe.js I send it down as a prop:

```
<Comments comments={this.props.location.state.recipe.Comments} />
```

I'm guessing this happens because I send the recipe through `location` and not `props`?
But I don't know how to change it so that it will work and re-render upon Commend beeing Added.

This is my code in App.js when adding a comment:

```
addComment(key, aComment)
{
    aComment['UserID'] = this.state.currentUser.m;
    aComment['Time'] = new Date().getTime();

    const commentRef = firebase.database().ref(`/recipes/${key}/Comments`);

    commentRef.push(aComment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the component state in the constructor from the location prop

Comment: This doesn't work for me I must be missing something more if this should work.

Comment: And you are saying that the state in the App.js is updating,but it is not propagating

Comment: LatestRecipes component is updating correctly but the other are sending data down through NavLink